# How to make total price system of suppliers in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So my question is how to make total price system of suppliers in PHP & MySQL. I have 3 columns id, supplier, dues.I want all dues sum column in front of its supplier only one time(not loop).Here is my code

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM managment WHERE id=$id";
  $query = mysqli_query($connection, $result);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['supplier']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['dues']; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

But this code showing loop values of supplier according to db rows.How can i manage all dues in one column. Hope you understand guys.Please help me.Thanks

Comment: `Select sum(dues) from managment WHERE id=$id`; or I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Don't you think you need to show the DataBase Structure and contents and your expected output and we can't deduce anything from what you have written? `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have multiple records for the same supplier with different due values, if so you just need to alter your query.

`SELECT id, supplier, SUM(dues) as total FROM management GROUP BY supplier`

However seeing as you are specifying the primary key this may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Or `GROUP BY id`, but the problem here will be more if `supplier` is taken from another relation, making your answer invalid.

Comment: @HelloSpeakman you are right... it's worked thanks

Comment: If this has helped please mark as accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @PraveenKumar although it's quite easily understandable from the sql provided, it's not taken from another relation, it's also (semantically) deducible that OP wants to base sum of `dues`, per `supplier`

Comment: @Cemal Right! `:)`